# Call Fragment width from other Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I call `Fragment` in layout using

```
LinearLayout formLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
formLayout.removeAllViews();

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =      fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
PatientSearch fragment = new PatientSearch(maincontrolActivity.this);

fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mainLayout,fragment, "MY_FRAG");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Within `PatientSearch` I have button I want when click on load another `Fragment` but within the boundry of the old `Fragment`.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't call `Fragment`s (or perform `FragmentTransactions`) within a `Fragment`. `Fragment`s should never interact with other `Fragment`s directly, as this would go against their whole purpose (they are meant to be designed for reuse, as stated in the documentation).

What you should do instead is create an event callback in the `Activity`. Your `Fragment`s should call the `Activity` and then the `Activity` should then direct the call to the other `Fragment`. This may sound like extra work, but good design can go a long way and make your life easier down the line.

Comment: This section in the documentation describes the process. The sample code implements a multipane layout, with the left pane being a listview, and the right pane being a details view. Each time you press a list item in the left pane, the details fragment changes. This is done using a callback event to the activity, as described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks

Comment: Reading the *entire* documentation one more time, just to completely understand fragments and their purpose, will help immensely in your understanding as well